# Tomcat cant access network drives on Windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, windows-server-2012, resources, network-share

I have Tomcat 8 installed as a service on Windows Server 2012. The problem is that **Tomcat can't access network drives**. The tomcat manager shows that it is logged on as `Local System Account`. I've changed that to `This account` and selected the current user which i use to get logged in on Windows and this user can see the network drives. Can you tell me how to configure Tomcat so that it could be able to access network drives?

Answer (score 1):

It can't access the network drives because it's running as `NT authority\Local System`.  `NT authority\Local System` doesn't have network access, because it's **local**.  Says so right in the name.  (And `NT authority\Local Service` has the same restriction, of course.)

The equivalent of `NT authority\Local System`, with network access, is `NT authority\Network Service`, so set it to run under that account.

[`NT authority\Network Service` does not have a password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but should ignore any password you do provide, so you ought to be fine specifying anything, or nothing, depending on your application's behavior.  (If your application requires a value for the password, you should be able to set it to anything and be alright.)

Comment: What password should i set?

Comment: It doesn't have a password, and calls ignore any password specified.  So you should be able to set anything (or nothing), and be fine.

Comment: I made that change, but not i have no access to the web page i was requesting. Before of the change it was working, but not now.

Comment: @FernandoPrieto 1) You said network drives, and mentioned nothing about a webpage.  2) How are the permissions set on the network drive/webpage/whatever?  Using the network service account allows the system to access the network, but network resources still need to have the permissions set to allow this system to access them.

Comment: I have a web page running on Tomcat. The framework i use (Apache Cocoon) needs to access a file that is located on a network drive but it can´t since tomcat can not access them. The same problem occurs with another web page that runs on the same Tomcat and attempts to save a file on a network drive. This tomcat is running as service on the server.